# What OS X Timer Application emulates the functions of iOS's stopwatch (clock) app?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I am searching for a OS X Timer/Stop Watch application which provides functionality to start or stop a timed counter?

Something that looks and works just like the iOS Stopwatch and Timer function would be perfect.

It doesn't have to look exactly the same as the iOS app and should have keyboard shortcuts rather than need touch screen / mouse interaction.

Comment: Searching for [OSX timer app](https://www.google.ch/search?q=osx+timer+app) on Google reveals a ton of hits. If non of them matches your requirements, please refine your question.

Comment: @patrix You are 100% correct - I've gone ahead and added some specificity - Hopefully Maxcode feels the same or can edit out my preferences and in theirs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the Mac App Store has some awesome options - some free, the rest extremely reasonably priced.

Have a look at:

- [Menu Timer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/menutimer/id595968424?mt=12)
- [My Alarm Clock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-alarm-clock/id494841448?mt=12) (and it's free cousin, [Alarm Clock](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock/id582657740?mt=12))

Depending on how much timing and alarming you need, there are even amazing programmable timers like [FlexTime](http://www.red-sweater.com/flextime/)